# editing categorical data for uniformity

Tags: sas

i have 1 million + rows of data and on of the columns is channel_name.  The people collecting the data didn't seem to care that they entered one channel in about 10 different variations, lots of which contain the @ symbol.  Google search isn't giving me any decent documentation, can anyone direct me to something useful?

Comment: try pattern matching [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/278.html) using proc sql

Comment: Since it is owned by SAS, Dataflux is maybe worth mentioning. It is a different product (with close integration into SAS) that is aimed exactly at data cleaning, including things like you mention. Of course, if this is really the only instance where you have such a problem, it is most likely overkill.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent the answer has to be, "it depends".  Your actual data will determine the best solution to this; and there may not be one true solution - you may have to try a few things, and there may well be more manual work than you'd like.

One option is to build a format based on what you see.  That format can either convert various values to one consistent value, or convert to a numeric category (which is then overlaid with a format that shows the consistent value).

For example, you might have 'channel' as retail store:
    data have;
    infile datalines truncover;
    input @1 channel $8.;
    datalines;
    Best Buy
    BestBuy
    BB
    ;;;;
    run;

So you can do one of two things:

```
proc format;
value $channel
"Best Buy","BB","BestBuy" = "Best Buy";
quit;

data want;
set have;
channel_coded = put(channel,$channel.);
run;
```

Or you can do:

```
proc format;
invalue channeli
"Best Buy", "BB","BestBuy" = 1
;
value channelf
1 = "Best Buy"
;
quit;


data want;
set have;
channel_coded = input(channel,CHANNELI.);
format channel_coded channelf.;
run;
```

Which you do is largely up to you - the latter gives you more flexibility in the long run, for example when Sears and K-Mart merged, it would be somewhat to take 2 and 16 and format then as Sears, than to change the stored values for the character format - and even easier to roll back if/when KMart splits off again.

This does require some manual work, though; you have to code things by hand here, or develop some method for figuring out what the coding is.  You can use the `other` option in proc format to easily identify new values and add them to the format (which can be derived from a dataset, instead of hand written code), but at the end of the day the actual values you have determine what solution is best for the actual work of determining what is "Best Buy", and a by-hand solution (each time a new value comes in, it is looked at by a person and coded) may ultimately be the best.

Comment: This is a good approach.  Not only are formats very efficient (in-memory lookups) they are also a lot easier to 'read' than, say, hash tables (so better for other programmers to understand what you have done)